# what type is this ? Is there an NSList option in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I've been learning how to work with APIs with Swift lately and I've come into a question of what type of data is this in swift? According to the company's API it's a List[LeagueEntryDto] data type. Here's the output

```
{"24874695": [{
  "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
  "name": "Twitch's Captains",
  "entries": [{
       "leaguePoints": 35,
       "isFreshBlood": false,
       "isHotStreak": false,
       "division": "III",
       "isInactive": false,
       "isVeteran": false,
       "losses": 34,
       "playerOrTeamName": "AerialStability",
       "playerOrTeamId": "24874695",
       "wins": 24
  }],  
 "tier": "SILVER"
 }]}
```

How do I get the specific item in "entries"?

Here's my code:

```
        var summonerLeague = NSURL(string: "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v2.5/league/by-summoner/\(summonerID)/entry?api_key=dec19325-8a2c-4377-9e47-4a1fb00a930c")
        var dataLeague = NSData(contentsOfURL: summonerLeague!)


           if dataLeague != nil {
              let summonerLeagueDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataLeague!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as! NSDictionary
              println(summonerID)
              //print(summonerLeagueDict)

        //find summoner League Division
            if let summLeague: AnyObject
                = summonerLeagueDict["\(summonerID)"] {
            //println(summLeague)
            // cannot find list
            if let summEntry: AnyObject = summLeague[0] {
                println(summEntry["tier"]!)
                println(summEntry["name"]!)

             // nothing comes out of here. This is the part in question
                if let summDiv = summEntry["entries"] as? NSDictionary{
                    println("this is NOT printed")
                    println(summDiv["division"])
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Dictionary. The key, "24874695", has an Array for value. This array contains a Dictionary, and this Dictionary contains an array, and this array contains a Dictionary. :)

This is a JSON object, so you can follow the collection types knowing that `{}` is the delimiter for dictionaries and `[]` is the delimiter for arrays.

A quick example of how to get the first "entries" field:

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let entries = json["24874695"]?[0]["entries"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        println(entries)
    }
}
```

Result:

> [[playerOrTeamName: AerialStability, isHotStreak: 0, isFreshBlood: 0, wins: 24, playerOrTeamId: 24874695, losses: 34, isInactive: 0, isVeteran: 0, leaguePoints: 35, division: III]]

And you can loop in the data like this:

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] {
    for (key, value) in json as [String:AnyObject] {
        println(key)
        for item in value as! [[String:AnyObject]] {
            println(item["entries"]!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's so awesome! Thank you Eric!

Answer (score 0):

declaring the type as AnyObject will fail always, you have to cast the object to something more specific, for example (untested)

```
if let summLeague = summonerLeagueDict["\(summonerID)"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
    //println(summLeague)
    // cannot find list
    if let summEntry = summLeague[0] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
      println(summEntry["tier"] as! String)
      println(summEntry["name"] as! String)

      // nothing comes out of here. This is the part in question
      if let summDiv = summEntry["entries"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
        println("this is NOT printed")
        println(summDiv["division"] as! String)
      }
  }
}
```

check with the `println()`lines where you are